# How to parse a object using gson having symbols in key names

Tags: java, parsing, gson

I need to parse below json to object but I'm not sure how to do it.

```
"StatusText" : {"@Code":32, "@Val":452, "$": "available"}
```

There are some special characters in the name of the keys. How can i parse this to below object using gson.

```
class StatusText {
   private int code;
   private int val;
   private String status;
   ...
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `@SerializedName` annotation, see https://howtodoinjava.com/gson/gson-serializedname/

Example for your code:

```
@SerializedName("@Code")
private int code;
@SerializedName("@Val")
private int val;
```

Comment: I have dollar  sign instead of Code or Val